# Structuring MySQL query efficiently

Tags: php, mysql, performance, html-table

I'm looking for some help in how best to structure a MySQL query and display the results. I am trying to create a table on a PHP page which has 7 dates across the top and room numbers down the side. In the table, if a person is in a room on the given date then their name appears. I have the following tables:

**Table:** rooms
**Fields:** id, room

**Table:** bookings
**Fields:** id, name, room, checkin, checkout

The code I currently have is:

```
<? $start = date('Y-m-d'); 
$end = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($start." + 6 day")); ?>
<table class="table1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th scope="col"><?= date('d-m', strtotime($start)); ?></th>
            <th scope="col"><?= date('d-m', strtotime($start." + 1 day")); ?></th>
            <th scope="col"><?= date('d-m', strtotime($start." + 2 day")); ?></th>
            <th scope="col"><?= date('d-m', strtotime($start." + 3 day")); ?></th>
            <th scope="col"><?= date('d-m', strtotime($start." + 4 day")); ?></th>
            <th scope="col"><?= date('d-m', strtotime($start." + 5 day")); ?></th>
            <th scope="col"><?= date('d-m', strtotime($start." + 6 day")); ?></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>   
        <? $q1 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM rooms GROUP BY room");
        while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q1)){ ?>
            <tr>
                <th><?= $row1['room']; ?></th>
                <? $i = 0;
                while ($i <= 6) { ?>
                    <td>
                        <? $q2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE ((checkin BETWEEN '$start' and '$end') or (checkout BETWEEN '$start' and '$end') or (checkin <= '$start' AND checkout >= '$end')) and room = '$row1[room]'");
                        while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q2)){                             
                            if ($row2['checkout'] > date('Y-m-d', strtotime($start." + ".$i." day")) and $row2['checkin'] <= date('Y-m-d', strtotime($start." + ".$i." day"))) {
                                echo $row2['name'];
                            } 
                        } ?>
                    </td>
                <? ++$i;
                } ?>     
          </tr>
        <? } ?>    
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This code currently produces the result I need however, I'm worried that it's inefficient because of the amount of loops and queries it runs to get the data.

Can anyone suggest a better way of formatting the query/result?

Comment: Start by learning about SQL JOINS

Comment: Might want to have a google for mysql pivot query

Comment: Remember, time is linear, so you're only interested in time where x_start is < y_end AND x_end > y_start!

Answer (score 0):

I think the logic you want in the `where` clause is:

```
checkin <= '$end' AND checkout >= '$start' and room = '$row1[room]'
```

A room is occupied between the two dates when the checking is before the end date and the checkout is after the start date.

EDIT:

The clause you have is:

```
checkin <= '$start' AND checkout >= '$end'
```

That is different from my solution.

Comment: Hi Gordon. I think I already have this clause in my second query (q2). The problem is, if there are 20 rooms then that would mean 140 queries need to run to display the information. This is what I am trying to reduce/make more efficient if possible? Thanks.